# How to deal with questions like "where is this expression valid"?

Tags: discusión

Consider the question
[¿Cuál es el origen del modismo "es equis" para decir que algo no es malo ni bueno, sino "más o menos"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5135/donde-se-usa-es-equis-para-decir-que-algo-no-es-malo-ni-bueno-sino-mas-o-me)  I tried to answer it, and long thereafter I realized, that, as is the case with many other questions of the type "where is valid *this* or *that*  expression?", it's impossible to deliver a unique answer. One comes to that conclusion as follows.

Lot of people of lots of regions are allowed to say, "this is valid on *my* country or my region". Which answer should be there preferred over the others? No region can be preferred over other.

Even forgetting this issue, if we would be able to gather the information of lots of regions where that expression is usual, how would we know the information is complete?

Therefore, I ask here

*Which is the wisest approach to those questions*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) rules, that kind of question would end closed as too broad

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. 
>   Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

I think the question can be more fit for this site if the OP enclosing the question to a more specific country or zone.

At the question you show as example, the OP at the end did a valid question

> ¿Cuál es su origen?

Comment: Well, sad thing is, sometimes one doesn't have idea about the validity of an expression in one's whole country. That is, Spanish also varies *inside* the country. Which makes things interesting, but also complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Many of these questions do have concrete answers.  But you're probably right that they don't generally have very *useful* answers.

What is probably best is to ask a slight variation, depending on the specific needs of the OP.  Some suggestions might be:

- Is this term/phrase used universally?
- Is there any place this term/phrase would not be understood, and is there a better, more universal alternative?

In the particular example you provided, I have edited the question to not focus on the rationality of the phrase, which on closer inspection, wasn't really that interesting or central to the question in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I think that country sub-tags should be enabled and rewarded for all questions that have the tag "regionalim".

For example, someone asks a question about the use of "vos" instead of "tu". Then the OP, or a high ranking user puts the tag "regionalism" and each user that puts a country tag for the places where the "vos" is used gets a point.
If the tag gets removed, the abusing user loses 2 points (instead of the one that he got for tagging)

In this specific case:

- User A asks a question about the use "vos" and tags it as regional.
- User B gets 2 points for adding Uruguay and Argentina.
- User C gets 1 point for adding Maracaibo.
- User D gets one point for adding Mexico, then loses 2 points when a
  senior user removes the tag Mexico.

Comment: Sounds cool. Just that I wouldn't know how to implement this voting system. I'm not alluding to the techincal implementation, but, for instance in [that very question](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/5191/768), another guy gave an answer. He claims in Mexico *chale* is not used. See the problem? Not even a country is considered an isolated enough region where Spanish is uniform. And for Maracaibo, Montevideo, etc. I'm not sure we can make a tag. We certainly can, but, then every post would be full of tags.

Comment: This wouldn't be practical, considering a question can have at most 5 tags (so 'regionalism' plus up to 4 countries).  It would also require a new feature to assign reputation points to tags.