# Answering questions with unspecified region

Tags: discusión

So, I got into a little chat in the comments today, in [this question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5236/cual-es-el-verbo-para-party-en-espanol).

> Como se dice "I want to party tonight" Yo se que se puede decir, "Quiero ir a una fiesta esta noche" pero estoy buscando un verbo que tiene el mismo efecto.

My answer:

> "Festejar".
>   Translating your example, it would end up being something like:
>   ¡Esta noche quiero festejar!
>   You can also use "Celebrar", which translates to "Celebrate". It depends on the context. For this particular translation, I'd go with "Festejar".

I answered the question as it was specified (that is, with no region specified). It was pointed out that the answer be prone to misunderstandings in some regions.

What I want to know is: is the question valid in the first place? And if it is, what is the correct way to answer it?

Comment: check this http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2474/faq-on-topic-off-topic-list-revisal/2482#2482

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Is the question valid in the first place?

Considering that the OP may not be aware of any regional differences, I think it is not reasonable to request that all the vocabulary questions must state a region of interest.

## And if it is, what is the correct way to answer it?

Similarly, considering that the person writing an answer may not be aware of any regional differences, I would suggest that when it becomes apparent that the regional differences are important, then the answer is updated highlighting those differences.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, I guess if the question specifies a particular region, and those kind of questions become common, we could add region-specific tags.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that we will inevitably become aware of the importance of regional differences only after it's too late. Specifically, after we have multiple, contradicting, regional answers. At that point, editing the question renders one or more existing answers obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

Recently was discusse something related [How to deal with questions like "where is this expression valid"?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338/how-to-deal-with-questions-like-where-is-this-expression-valid)

How I posted in that question I think that kind of question should be closed as too broad. As you may know this site is still young and I think we need to create the rules or improve the rules that are already.

It's important to check the help center, and the reasons in the flag popup there and if is necessary plan an update.

Also a request, I don't know if it's possible, include some info in Spanish in the help center or about page to guide the new users

As always in the Stack Exchange Network the community can propose whatever change they think is necessary with the help of the moderators.

Comment: I tried to find some info in other language SE sites, but I didn't quite find much about it. In English, they have different tags for regions, I think this approach can work in the future (having a mexican-spanish, cuban-spanish, latin-american-spanish, spain-spanish, etc).

Comment: But as it was stated above, it should not be a requirement for the question.

Comment: We have to propose to the moderators I think, it's a good idea