# Are some questions inherently prone to getting only regional answers?

Tags: discusión

Possible duplicate of [Answering questions with unspecified region](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/345/6804) but not quite the same thing.

[This question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/4701/6804)'s answers are mostly regional variants of the same phrase and the quality of said answers isn't exactly *great*.

Should these questions be handled in a way that the answers are a collection of wiki community answers? I've seen that before when asking about certain phrases and other obviously regional-based questions.

- How should these questions be handled?
- Should speakers be obligated to include where they're from/where they grew up?
- Should the asker specify a region or should there be a collection of different answers and let them pick whatever they find best?
- Is there a way to objectively accept an answer in this type of question?